# Adding a date range to existing query

Tags: date-range

I have just started a new job and am working with existing queries. As I am no expert on SQL I'm wondering if a date range such as 2015-8-1 through 2015-8-31 can be inserted into the query below. Any help offered is greatly appreciated.

```
    SELECT 
 RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DoctorFacility.ListName ORDER BY ApptSlot.Start)     
as SlotNumber
 , DoctorFacility.ListName as ProviderName
 , ApptSlot.Start as ApptStartTime
 , AppointmentsAlloc.Type as ApptType

 INTO #TEMP

 FROM CentricityPS.dbo.ApptSlot ApptSlot 
 INNER JOIN CentricityPS.dbo.AppointmentsAlloc AppointmentsAlloc 
ON ApptSlot.ApptSlotId=AppointmentsAlloc.ApptSlotId
 INNER JOIN CentricityPS.dbo.Schedule Schedule 
ON ApptSlot.ScheduleId=Schedule.ScheduleId
 INNER JOIN CentricityPS.dbo.DoctorFacility DoctorFacility 
ON Schedule.DoctorResourceId=DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId
 WHERE AppointmentsAlloc.Type IN
(
'Behavioral Health - 30' 
,'Behavioral Health 45' 
,'Established Patient - 15' 
,'Established Patient - 20' 
,'Fin Counsel - 30' 
,'Gyn Visit - 15' 
,'Pediatric Visit - 15'
) 
 AND ApptSlot.ListOrder=1 
 AND ApptSlot.Status IS  NULL  
 AND ApptSlot.Start>= GETDATE()
 ORDER BY DoctorFacility.ListName

SELECT 
ProviderName
, ApptStartTime
, ApptType

FROM #TEMP
WHERE SlotNumber = 3
ORDER BY ProviderName

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate select queries here.  It would be done the same way for either part of the query regardless. Just add it to your WHERE statement

```
  AND ApptSlot.Start>= 2015-8-1 
  AND ApptSlot.Start<= 2015-8-31
```

Another syntax would be

```
  AND ApptSlot.Start between 2015-8-1 and 2015-8-31
```

Ideally you want to pass those begin and start dates as variables so values would not be hard coded.  It might look more like this.

```
   AND ApptSlot.Start between @StartDate and @EndDate
```